# How to create matrix of all 2^n binary sequences of length n using recursion in R?

Tags: r, recursion, binary

I know I can use expand.grid for this, but I am trying to learn actual programming. My goal is to take what I have below and use a recursion to get all 2^n binary sequences of length n.

I can do this for n = 1, but I don't understand how I would use the same function in a recursive way to get the answer for higher dimensions.

Here is for n = 1:

```
binseq <- function(n){
  binmat <- matrix(nrow = 2^n, ncol = n)
  r <- 0 #row counter
  for (i in 0:1) {
        r <- r + 1
        binmat[r,] <- i
    }
  return(binmat)
  }
```

I know I have to use probably a cbind in the return statement. My intuition says the return statement should be something like cbind(binseq(n-1), binseq(n)). But, honestly, I'm completely lost at this point.

The desired output should basically recursively produce this for n = 3:

```
binmat <- matrix(nrow = 8, ncol = 3)
r <- 0 # current row of binmat
for (i in 0:1) {   
for (j in 0:1) {
for (k in 0:1) {
r <- r + 1
binmat[r,] <- c(i, j, k)}   
} 
}
binmat
```

It should just be a matrix as binmat is being filled recursively.

Comment: You example function produces NA in the matrix. Can you fix it or provide your desired output?

Comment: it shouldn't for binseq(1). My issue is generalizing to n > 1 using recursion. A desired output has also been added.

Answer (score 0):

I quickly wrote this function to generate all **N^K** permutations of length **K** for given **N** characters. Hope it will be useful.

```
gen_perm <- function(str=c(""), lst=5, levels = c("0", "1", "2")){
  if (nchar(str) == lst){
    cat(str, "\n")
    return(invisible(NULL))
  }
  for (i in levels){
    gen_perm(str = paste0(str,i), lst=lst, levels=levels)
  }
}

# sample call
gen_perm(lst = 3, levels = c("x", "T", "a"))
```

I will return to your problem when I get more time.

**UPDATE**
I modified the code above to work for your problem. Note that the matrix being populated lives in the global environment. The function also uses the `tmp` variable to pass rows to the global environment. This was the easiest way for me to solve the problem. Perhaps, there are other ways.

```
levels <- c(0,1)
nc <- 3

m <- matrix(numeric(0), ncol = nc)

gen_perm <- function(row=numeric(), lst=nc, levels = levels){
  if (length(row) == lst){
    assign("tmp", row, .GlobalEnv)
    with(.GlobalEnv, {m <- rbind(m, tmp); rownames(m) <- NULL})
    return(invisible(NULL))
  }
  for (i in levels){
    gen_perm(row=c(row,i), lst=lst, levels=levels)
  }
}

gen_perm(lst=nc, levels=levels)
```

**UPDATE 2**
To get the expected output you provided, run

```
m <- matrix(numeric(0), ncol = 3)
gen_perm(lst = 3, levels = c(0,1))
m
```

`levels` specifies a range of values to generate (binary in our case) to generate permutations, `m` is an empty matrix to fill up, `gen_perm` generates rows and adds them to the matrix `m`, `lst` is a length of the permutation (matches the number of columns in the matrix).

Comment: I mostly understand what this is doing, though I'm looking for a more numerical approach, rather than pasting characters. I'll see if this helps me understand where I'm going wrong, though more help would certainly be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: not exactly. it's far beyond my level. i'm basically working through a text book and i changed my expected answer to show exactly what it is i'm trying to replicate but recursively for large n.

My original "solution," or first step really, doesn't even generate all the possibilities for just n = 1 technically.

Comment: @Michael I included an example and some clarifications to my post above.