# R: all combinations of nested list of variable length

Tags: r, list, nested, combinations

I am sure this must have a solution somewhere here but I really failed to find it. There is something along the same [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57448008/how-to-create-all-combinations-from-a-nested-list-while-preserving-the-structure), but then not really.
Say I have a nested list of variable lengths - below length is 2:

`L = list('Z1' = c('z11', 'z12'), 'Z2' = c('z21', 'z22', 'z23'))`

How do I get in base R all combinations of sublists. For short lists like `L` one would do for instance:

```
> expand.grid(L[[1]], L[[2]])
  Var1 Var2
1  z11  z21
2  z12  z21
3  z11  z22
4  z12  z22
5  z11  z23
6  z12  z23
```

But how is this achieved in the general case ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233742/permutations-of-a-list-of-lists. Edit: sorry, that's python.. Anyway, what you should search for is how to generate permutations.

Comment: @joran Goddamit. (Torkel Velure: year Ihats Python).

Comment: @user3375672 Look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58399137/how-to-create-matrix-of-all-2n-binary-sequences-of-length-n-using-recursion-in/58400455#58400455)